# Javascript not loading properly under some circumstances

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, https

We've got a website(with HTTPS) with jQuery and Javascript. We noticed that under some circumstances the Javascript simply won't load. In console, it simply prints out some JS error(undefined) but I can't tell it's because the js file is not getting included or there is some syntax error somewhere.

It happens when I use some Guest internets(Tried the guest Wifi in stanford university & emory university). And sometimes it just happens even I'm in the office, and it will be fine again in like 10 minutes. It only happens to some computers as well in the office(All MAC OSX w/ safari) and some of them are fine. To be it's like totally random unless I'm under some guest wifi.

What could be the reasons?

Best,
Jack

---

Edit:
Someone feels like it's too board, sorry for the issue but I'm doing my best to describe the problem. This happens in a random manner and it won't get fixed by refreshing the page when it happens.  And all the javascript files are included in a https way.

Edit:
I noticed that on some circumstances, I have functions defined **after** the place they are called. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Sounds like a race condition. Are you loading any scripts asynchronously? Do you use a script loader?

Comment: Did you use the network tab in the Chrome (Firefox, IE > 8, Safari, etc.) tools to confirm what exactly is coming over the wire?

Comment: @jameslafferty No I just checked the console. I counld't really find the network tab in my safari, any ideas about where that is?

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme I think I load my live chat asynchronously. But I feel like the issue existed before i have the live chat integrated (not sure tho). How should I check this? Can you be a little bit more specific about this race condition? Did you mean like live chat is being called before socket.io is loaded maybe? But refresh the page does not change the result, it's still not loaded until you wait for a while. then everything is fine even u refresh.

Comment: This is indeed very broad, as there is no way we can give a definitive answer, all we can do is guess as to what might be possible reasons. My advice for debugging this would be that as a first step you should look at the network traffic, f.e. using your browser’s developer tools. Does anything stand out there in the cases where you experience this error – any aborted connections, unexpected HTTP errors, …?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your help. I've been using consoles / tools like firebugs to observe this, but all i got are some JS errors (undefined functions). And it will be gone if i change to another network.

Comment: @jackhao In Safari, it's under timelines > network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Jquery CDN that supports https, or put the code on your own site/server and include it from your domain.  Here are two examples which will work over ssl.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I generally trust google libraries as a cdn, its up to you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://mysite.com/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to trust google you can deploy it on your own.

Comment: Ok, well here is my advice then.  Try and find a network that causes this bug and copy/paste the src of the js file you are importing into a browser and see if you can access the file.  If you can & the src starts with https:// then its very likely the issue isn't with the cdn

Comment: The site is a large site with multiple layouts, codes are very, very long. I won't be able to post it here. Thank you for the suggestion! I think the files are accessible tho. No 404 errors returned in console.

Comment: Well then I've no idea.  Unless the guest network is blocking your CDN(very unlikely) and as long as you are using a ssl cdn it should be working.  If you see that the file is loaded in your sources it should work.  Please post the errors you said you are getting, its hard to help without any code/errors

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a lot of people leave the protocol out so that it automatically uses the current protocol:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: I'm doing https:// for all the included scripts now, will it make any difference? The whole site is only accessible via https and will redirect to https if you try to access from http in htaccess.

Comment: It depends on how your web server is set up to load static files, but I think if everything loads via the same protocol it wouldn't matter

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that this may not be a 100% solution.  After testing more, on occasion I still see that my at least one of my js files doesnt load.  I am hosting all of my js files on the website itself which makes me think that shifting everything to load from a CDN might be best option.

I also include all of the site specific js code in the page itself instead of trying to load another js file.

--

Just to let you know, I was having the same issue on one of my websites.  The whole site runs under https and occasionally when i would visit one of my pages for whatever reason the javascript files would not load.  I think this occurs because https does tend to slow down the overall connection.

Here is how i fixed my issue:

1. Place all js files before the closing body tag.
2. Load all primary js files from a reliable CDN that supports https (others have mentioned CDNs like Google etc).

Perhaps a combination of loading the scripts from a CDN and also placing the lines at the bottom of the page will help ensure that everything loads properly.

Another suggestion, might be to combine all of your websites js files into one file so there are less concurrent js requests.

I believe all of these problems stem from slow connections related to https and poor connection speeds.